# Explain Ruby loops compared to Java

Tags: java, ruby, arrays, loops, iteration

In Java you have to specify what value you are going to increase and by how much. In Ruby is seems you can set each value of say an array to some random variable and it auto increments. This bugs me so much because even though I understand what is going on I can't wrap my head around how you would get finer control. What if I wanted to increment by 2 or decrement? This is an example from codecademy.

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]

# Add your code below!
odds.each do |item|
    item *= 2
    print item
end
```

I understand it's iterating over each element in the array but where does item come from? Do you just pull it out of the sky and ruby initializes it to the particular element you are iterating over? Also how do you specify how you want to increment? What if I only want every other element in the array?

Comment: Java also has iterators, so this shouldn't cause your head to explode unless your understanding of Java is not as solid as you seem to think.

Comment: It just seems Ruby does a lot for you where in Java you have to do everything for yourself. I'm not use to it.

Comment: That's a good thing.  Learn to love it.

Comment: `each` is a method for collections. It receives, as parameter, a `block`. All content between `do` and `end` is a block. As described in `each` documentation, Ruby will apply the given block code to each collection item. Inside this block, you can give a name to current item (in the sample code called just `item`). Java 8 appears to have a similar approach using [Lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: um you are confusing a for loop with a foreach loop

Comment: Groovy has equivalents of Ruby's iterators, ranges, and other loop constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` is an *iterator* method which works with a code *block*: it iterates over the items in an array (or dictionary), in the order given within the array, and passes the iterating values, one at a time.

`item` is set to each value from the object on which the `each` method was called.

The general syntax is:

```
ARRAY.each do |var| CODE-USING-var end
```

or

```
ARRAY.each {|var| CODE-USING-var }
```

both syntaxes have equivalent meaning.  There is a convention to use `do` - `end` pairs on larger blocks of code, but it's just a convention.

There is a related method called `each_with_index`, which produces two values on each iteration: the item value, and the index (starting with 0) of that item within the object.

Example:
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
words = %w( now is the time for all good men )
def show_words list
  puts "---"
  list.each_with_index do
    |word,x|
    puts "word #{x} = #{word}"
  end
end
show_words words
show_words words.reverse
show_words words.sort`

Here is the invocation:

```
./t2.rb
---
word 0 = now
word 1 = is
word 2 = the
word 3 = time
word 4 = for
word 5 = all
word 6 = good
word 7 = men
---
word 0 = men
word 1 = good
word 2 = all
word 3 = for
word 4 = time
word 5 = the
word 6 = is
word 7 = now
---
word 0 = all
word 1 = for
word 2 = good
word 3 = is
word 4 = men
word 5 = now
word 6 = the
word 7 = time
```

Comment: So with the each_with_index I'm guessing you can filter x so you could increment by whatever you wanted.

Comment: Yes, if you wish to iterate over sub-parts of the array, it's probably best to filter it and then run an `each` over the items that are desired.  For example: `somearray.grep(/somepattern/).each{|item| process(item)}`.  

But, you could just as easily filter on values of `x` with `each_with_index`, as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby code fragment you provided is essentially the same as this Java fragment:

```
  int[] odds = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

  for(int item : odds) {
     item *= 2;
     System.out.println(item);
  }
```

Both Ruby and Java provide iterators for collections.  They also both provide other looping or iterating constructs if you want them.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is not a loop. It is simply a method of the `Array` class which `yield`s each item in turn to a block.

Note that this is no different from Java, it is, in fact, *exactly* equivalent to [`java.lang.Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
List<Integer> odds = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9 );

odds.forEach(item -> {
  item *= 2;
  System.out.println(item);
});
```

The implementation of `Array#each` in Ruby looks a little bit like this:

```
class Array
  def each
    howmany = size
    i = -1

    while i+=1 < howmany
      yield self[i]
    end
  end
end
```